# EF: How do I use a Field of Type Edm.Time backed by a database column of type Datetime?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework-4

I've got a SQL table that has a column of type datetime, and an entity model to match. 
What I'd really like is for my Entity property to be of type Time, since I only care about the time portion. However, if I switch the type from DateTime to Time in the model, the EF complains, and I can't update the database to match.

What should I do?

Edit- Here's the partial class:

```
public partial class LineSchedule
{
    public TimeSpan TimeOfDay
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(XXTimeOfDay.Hour, XXTimeOfDay.Minute, XXTimeOfDay.Second);
            return ts;
        }
        set
        {
            this.XXTimeOfDay = new DateTime(XXTimeOfDay.Year, XXTimeOfDay.Month, XXTimeOfDay.Day,
                                    value.Hours, value.Minutes, value.Seconds);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Entity Framework produces partial classes, I would:

1. Change the name of the generated property
2. Make both the getter and setter private
3. Create a public property in a separate partial declaration
4. Use it's getter and setter to wrap the generated datetime as a Time.

Comment: I've tried that, but the EF gives me a "NotSupportedException" The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. I think that the setter gives the EF the impression that there should be some backing field..

Comment: @Jon Dewees - Update your original question with your partial class implementation for the TimeOfDay field. It sounds like something is a little off.

Comment: Updated question as requested.

Comment: @Jon Dewees - Do you have some leftover configuration of the TimeSpan field in the edmx file or something like that?